# Spring cassandra No node was available to execute the query

Tags: java, spring, cassandra, testcontainers

I'm writing integration tests for my Cassandra database, I use testcontainers 1.16.2 with Spring boot 2.6.1 and there's strange behaviour: the result of tests depends on which order they are being executed.

This is my application.yml:

```
spring:
  data:
    cassandra:
      keyspace-name: test_keyspace
      contact-points: localhost
      schema-action: create_if_not_exists
      port: 9042
      local-datacenter: datacenter1
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver
```

Cassandra config

```
@Configuration
@EnableCassandraRepositories(basePackages = { BASE_PACKAGE })
public class CassandraConfig {

    @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.contact-points}")
    private String contactPoints;
    @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.keyspace-name}")
    private String keyspaceName;
    @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.local-datacenter}")
    private String datacenterName;
    @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.port}")
    private int port;

    @Bean
    public CqlSessionFactoryBean session() {
        CqlSessionFactoryBean session = new CqlSessionFactoryBean();
        session.setContactPoints(contactPoints);
        session.setKeyspaceName(keyspaceName);
        session.setLocalDatacenter(datacenterName);
        session.setPort(port);
        return session;
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionFactoryFactoryBean sessionFactory(CqlSession session, CassandraConverter converter) {
        SessionFactoryFactoryBean sessionFactory = new SessionFactoryFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setSession(session);
        sessionFactory.setConverter(converter);
        sessionFactory.setSchemaAction(SchemaAction.NONE);

        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public CassandraMappingContext mappingContext(CqlSession cqlSession) {
        CassandraMappingContext mappingContext = new CassandraMappingContext();
        mappingContext.setUserTypeResolver(new SimpleUserTypeResolver(cqlSession));
        return mappingContext;
    }

    @Bean
    public CassandraConverter converter(CassandraMappingContext mappingContext) {
        return new MappingCassandraConverter(mappingContext);
    }

    @Bean
    public CassandraOperations cassandraTemplate(SessionFactory sessionFactory, CassandraConverter converter) {
        return new CassandraTemplate(sessionFactory, converter);
    }
}
```

Service

```
@Service
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class PersonService {

    private final PersonRepository repository;

    @Transactional
    @SneakyThrows
    public UUID createPerson(Person person) {
        UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();
        Person entity = new Person();
        entity.setId(id);
        entity.setName(person.getName());
        Person saved = repository.save(entity);
        return saved.getId();
    }
}
```

And this is my integration test

```
@Testcontainers
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = {IntegrationTest.PropertiesInitializer.class})
@Slf4j
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class IntegrationTest {

    private static final String KEYSPACE_NAME = "test_keyspace";

    @Container
    public static CassandraContainer<?> CASSANDRA = new CassandraContainer<>("cassandra:4.0.1")
            .withExposedPorts(9042)
            .withLogConsumer(new Slf4jLogConsumer(log))
            .withReuse(true);

    private static void executeStartQueries(Cluster cluster) {
        try (Session session = cluster.connect()) {
            session.execute("""
                    CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS %s WITH replication =
                     {'class':'SimpleStrategy','replication_factor':'1'};
                     """.formatted(KEYSPACE_NAME));
            session.execute("""
                    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  %s.Person (id uuid PRIMARY KEY, name text);
                    """.formatted(KEYSPACE_NAME));
        }
    }

    public static class PropertiesInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {

        @Override
        public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
            TestPropertyValues.of(
                    "spring.data.cassandra.port=" + CASSANDRA.getMappedPort(9042)
            ).applyTo(applicationContext.getEnvironment());
            executeStartQueries(CASSANDRA.getCluster());
        }
    }

    @Test
    void createPerson_Success() {
        UUID personId = service.createPerson(new Person().setName("name"));
        assertNotNull(personId);
    }
}
```

I also have other test classes. And if they run first, I have such exception and tests fail:

```
Query; CQL [INSERT INTO person (name,id) VALUES (?,?)]; No node was available to execute the query; nested exception is com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.NoNodeAvailableException: No node was available to execute the query
org.springframework.data.cassandra.CassandraConnectionFailureException: Query; CQL [INSERT INTO person (name,id) VALUES (?,?)]; No node was available to execute the query; nested exception is com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.NoNodeAvailableException: No node was available to execute the query
    at app//org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.CassandraExceptionTranslator.translate(CassandraExceptionTranslator.java:137)
    at app//org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.CassandraAccessor.translate(CassandraAccessor.java:422)
    at app//org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.CqlTemplate.translateException(CqlTemplate.java:764)
    at app//org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.CqlTemplate.query(CqlTemplate.java:545)
    at app//org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.doExecute(CassandraTemplate.java:959)
    at app//org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.doExecute(CassandraTemplate.java:947)
    at app//org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.executeSave(CassandraTemplate.java:898)
    at app//org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.executeSave(CassandraTemplate.java:889)
    at app//org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.doInsert(CassandraTemplate.java:700)
    at app//org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.doInsert(CassandraTemplate.java:683)
    at app//org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.insert(CassandraTemplate.java:664)
    at app//org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.support.SimpleCassandraRepository.save(SimpleCassandraRepository.java:96)
    at java.base@17.0.1/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base@17.0.1/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base@17.0.1/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base@17.0.1/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at app//org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289)
    at app//org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137)
    at app//org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121)
    at app//org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:529)
    at app//org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285)
    at app//org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:638)
    at app//org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at app//org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:163)
    at app//org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:138)
    at app//org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at app//org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80)
    at app//org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at app//org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at app//org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at app//org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
    at app/jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy144.save(Unknown Source)
    at app//com.pepsico.shelfIntelligence.service.impl.ModelMetadataServiceImpl.createModelMetadata(ModelMetadataServiceImpl.java:46)
    at app//com.pepsico.shelfIntelligence.service.ModelMetadataServiceImplTest.getModelMetadata_Success(ModelMetadataServiceImplTest.java:197)
    at java.base@17.0.1/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base@17.0.1/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base@17.0.1/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base@17.0.1/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at app//org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:725)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:214)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base@17.0.1/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base@17.0.1/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61)
    at java.base@17.0.1/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base@17.0.1/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base@17.0.1/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base@17.0.1/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at jdk.proxy1/jdk.proxy1.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$3.run(TestWorker.java:193)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:133)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:71)
    at app//worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
    at app//worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)
Caused by: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.NoNodeAvailableException: No node was available to execute the query
    at app//com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.NoNodeAvailableException.copy(NoNodeAvailableException.java:40)
    at app//com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.util.concurrent.CompletableFutures.getUninterruptibly(CompletableFutures.java:149)
    at app//com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlPrepareSyncProcessor.process(CqlPrepareSyncProcessor.java:59)
    at app//com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlPrepareSyncProcessor.process(CqlPrepareSyncProcessor.java:31)
    at app//com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.session.DefaultSession.execute(DefaultSession.java:230)
    at app//com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.cql.SyncCqlSession.prepare(SyncCqlSession.java:206)
    at app//org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate$PreparedStatementHandler.createPreparedStatement(CassandraTemplate.java:1082)
    at app//org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.CqlTemplate.query(CqlTemplate.java:531)
    ... 113 more
```

I have tried to debug my application, and I see that while executing this test, docker container with database is created, it has my keyspace and my table, I can execute queries. Also I tried to check my bean "CqlSessionFactoryBean" and it's connected to the right host/port/keyspace. So, I have no ideas why it is happening. If Spring executes this test class first, all tests are passed. But if another class first, this one fails Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue with a Spring Boot and Cassandra running in a Docker container.

make sure your `local-datacenter` value in the Spring Boot application.yml matches the value of the running Cassandra.

To find it, drop into the container and look for `cassandra-rackdc.properties` file. Mine was in `/opt//dse/resources/cassandra/conf/`.

```
# These properties are used with GossipingPropertyFileSnitch and will
# indicate the rack and dc for this node
dc=dc1
rack=rack1
```

Comment: Thanks. Your answer helped me out. I did a typo in the local-datacenter property and was facing the same issue.

Comment: where can I find cassandra-rackdc.properties file? I use cassandra:3.11.2